# Как в строке "Организация: %name% %inn%" выделить name и inn

Tags: javascript

Как в строке  "Организация: %name% %inn%" выделить name и inn в разные переменные?

Comment: Используйте `org_name.split(' ')[1]` и `org_name.split(' ')[2]` соответственно. Предполагается, что по крайней мере `%name%` не содержит пробелов. Если возможны ведущие или парные пробелы - их следует удалить перед выделением частей. См. [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант через регулярное выражение:

```js
var str = "Организация: %name% %inn%";
var re = /%(.*?)%/g;
var res;

if ((res = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  name = res[1];
  if ((res = re.exec(str)) !== null) inn = res[1];
}
console.log(name, inn);
```

Пример именно под вашу строку. Если переменных много, лучше делать в цикле while:

```js
var str = "Организация: %name% %inn%";
var re = /%(.*?)%/g;
var res, arr = [];

while ((res = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  arr.push(res[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```